# No setter/field for E7Dap0gODdUrzBC0Dnkn2jfoCbh1 found on class com.example.inquiryhome.model.User.UserDoctor

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i getting this error
No setter/field for E7Dap0gODdUrzBC0Dnkn2jfoCbh1 found on class com.example.inquiryhome.model.User.UserDoctor

this is the code with which I receive the data from firebase

```
 fun GetAllDoctor(): MutableLiveData<UserDoctor>{
    var liveData = MutableLiveData<UserDoctor>()
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    databaseReference.child("users").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                for(doctor in snapshot.children){
                    var userDoctor: UserDoctor = snapshot.getValue(UserDoctor::class.java)!!


                        liveData.value = userDoctor

                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "$error")
        }

    })

    return liveData
}
```

this is my class UserDoctor

```
data class UserDoctor (

val Id: String = "",
val Name: String? = null,
val Last_name: String? = null,
val Email: String = "",
val Birth: String? = null,
val Speciality: String? = null,
//val Image_Profile: Bitmap,
val Squatur: String = ""



)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read a `Doctor` from `/users` with:

```
var userDoctor: UserDoctor = snapshot.getValue(UserDoctor::class.java)!!
```

That should probably be:

```
var userDoctor: UserDoctor = doctor.getValue(UserDoctor::class.java)!!
```